# Select Upper 4 Edges of a UV Sphere

Tags: selection-tools

I would like to select the upper 4 edges of a UV sphere as shown below.. what are the steps to make this happen using a MAC IOS Blender

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go in top view

[image]

2. box select

[image]

3. hold down Shift and box select again

[image]

you will get:

[image]

Comment: thanks! I manually selected them one by one but this was indeed faster!

Comment: Gladly. if this helped you please tap on the checkmark left to my answer. Thank you!